# Storing images? Database or Filesystem on the cloud

Tags: database, azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I'm building a photo sharing app which has to store images. So I am thinking of using Azure mobile services for storing user data and links to their images stored in Azure Storage. The problem I think with this approach is that if the image is modified, there may not be referential integrity.

Is this a good approach or should I be storing both of these in the database(This approach is more expensive, monetarily).

PS: The images are standard images captured using a Mobile Camera.

Comment: This type of question (even if it has a practical solution) is opinion-based and off-topic. You've already received one answer which supports your idea. However, there's really no right answer to this. There's no single right place to store images, and no single right place to store references to those images.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I know that this question is opinion based but being new to backend development and developing a service that scales, I seek the option that seems best for my use-case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The approach you're thinking about taking (referencing the image from the structured data stored in Azure Mobile Apps) is good.

For the actual image storage, instead of using the file system on the service, the recommended approach would be to leverage something like Azure Blob Storage.

This recently published article about a new file management feature being added to Mobile Apps might be helpful (it should at least serve as guidance on how to manage file storage in the context of a mobile app):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/file-management-with-azure-mobile-apps/

I hope this helps!